# How to copy an object function when updating nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I have two pie charts that display the ratio of completed tasks for a given period, and a number of medals received for the period. The issue is that the state contains a function that is responsible for displaying tooltips when hovering over the charts, and so far the only way I've found to copy that function to the clone of the state, with which the state then gets updated, is by manually copying that function. For example, the function for the `completionRateData` state looks like this

```
function(context) {
 let value = context.formattedValue
 let sum = 0
 let dataArr = context.chart.data.datasets[0].data
 dataArr.map(data => {
 sum += Number(data)
})
 let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(0) + '%'
 return tasksForPeriod.length ? " " + percentage : ""
}
```

And this is how I'm currently updating the function in the state

```
completionRateClone.datasets[0].tooltip.callbacks.label =  function(context) {
      let value = context.formattedValue
      let sum = 0
      let dataArr = context.chart.data.datasets[0].data
      dataArr.map(data => {
          sum += Number(data)
      })
      let percentage = (value * 100 / sum).toFixed(0) + '%'
      return tasksForPeriod.length ? " " + percentage : ""
  }
```

The update happens in the `applyPeriod()` function right below the states. Here's the link to the editor https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdk3g?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: So if I got it right you want to update the field "label" (which is a function) using solely setCompletionRateData?

Comment: @underflow yes, I need to update that function in the state so that the data is rendered correctly. It's working right now, but like I said I'm just copy and pasting the original function manually.

Comment: I am posting an answer

Comment: btw in your stackblitz there's a typo watch out: setComppletionRateData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly update your state like the following:

```
setCompletionRateData((prevData) => ({
  ...prevData,
  datasets: prevData.datasets.map((dataset) => ({
    ...dataset,
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (context) {
          let value = context.formattedValue;
          let sum = 0;
          let dataArr = context.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
          dataArr.map((data) => {
            sum += Number(data);
          });
          let percentage = ((value * 100) / sum).toFixed(0) + '%';
          return tasksForPeriod.length ? ' ' + percentage : '';
        },
      },
    },
  })),
}));
```

Comment: Let me know if this works with you

Comment: Thank you, but I need to update other fields in the state as well, which I'm doing using the ```getCompletionRate()``` function, and they way I see it, my solution doesn't look very different from yours since the ```label``` function is still manually entered in the state, am I right?

Comment: So you want to call getCompletionRate again in the new state?

Comment: not quite, I use ```getCompletionRate``` to get new values that will be assigned to the updated state fields, you can see that in the first 7 lines of the ```applyPeriod``` function, for example I get a new lable value like so ```let newCompletionRateLabels = getCompletionRate(tasksForPeriod).labels``` and then assign that to the respective field in the cloned object ```completionRateClone.labels = newCompletionRateLabels```, once I've assigned all new values, the state is updated with this cloned object

Comment: Well I see... Then what you can do is simply pass the object (that you passed to useState) to the function setState

Comment: oh so it's not necessary to create a clone, I can just copy and paste that same exact object that I use in useState?

Comment: Most probably yes, please try to do so

Comment: it works, but how come it works only when manually entering the object, but doesn't when we copy it, regardless of whether it's a shallow or deep copy?

Comment: Not sure why, in all cases glad that my solution worked in your case. Can you please accept it?

Comment: And regarding the clone in your case (which I do not recommend), try this form to see if it works `setComppletionRateData(() => completionRateClone);`